# Obtener los 10 artículos más vendidos y ordenarlos de forma descendente

Tags: python

Como lo describí en el título, tengo que conseguir los diez títulos de productos principales tomando como referencia el número total de artículos vendidos. Los tengo que ordenar de forma descendente.

Tengo estas columnas con sus respectivos datos:

> 'trans_id', 'prod_upc', 'cust_id', 'trans_timestamp',
> 'trans_year','trans_month', 'trans_day', 'trans_hour',
> 'trans_quantity', 'cust_age','cust_state', 'prod_price', 'prod_title',
> 'prod_category', 'prod_animal_type', 'total_sales'

Intento resolverlo con este código:

```
top_diez=df_cleaned.groupby('prod_title')['trans_quantity'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False).head(10)
top_diez
```

Y me da error: me dice que tengo 1 o más productos que no son correctos. Y que verifique el orden de mi respuesta.

Comment: ¿Qué es ese `top_diez` al final de la asignación?

Comment: @CandidMoe, cuando usan JupyterLab o un ambiente similar no se necesita utilizar print, al escribir el nombre de la variable imprime el contenido

Comment: Es que aparecian en la misma línea por falta de formato.

Comment: Cuando utilizas `groupby` por defecto crea un nuevo índice o multi índice con la(s) columnas que usas para agrupar. Si estás trabajando con un sistema de evaluación automática como `hackerrank` tal vez quiere que la respuesta tenga los índices numéricos y no el título del producto.